# Firebase's ref().child(pathString: String) not working as expected;returning the parent along with it's neighbours rather than the node I'm asking for

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: db structure]

I'd like to fetch the members list in red. I'm instead returned each and everyone of the Activties:

[image: console output]

I've tried alot of variations, but I can't get more presice than this. Does Firebase only return top level objects or is my syntax off?

```
func updateActivity(activityUID: String, userUID: String) {
        var refs = Database.database().reference()
        print("Update \(activityUID) and add \(userUID) to members list")
        refs.child("Activties/\(activityUID)/members").getData { (error, snapshot) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error getting  data \(error)")
            }
            else if snapshot.exists() {
                print("Got data \(snapshot.value!)")
                var members = snapshot.value as? [String] ?? []
                print(members)
                members.append(userUID)
                print(members)
               // self.ref.child("\(activityUID)/members").setValue(members)
            }
            else {
                print("No data available")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code looks fine at first glance. Can you try using `.observeSingleEvent(of: .value`, just to see if that works? https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#read_data_once_with_an_observer

Answer (score 0):

I switched my db to Firestore. I can now update my array using a union function; the code for revised ActivityModel:

```
final class ActivitiesViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var db: Firestore
    @Published var activities: [Activity] = []
    
    init() {
        print("ActivitiesViewModel.swift init called")
        db = Firestore.firestore()
        fetchActivties()
    }
    func fetchActivties() {
        db.collection("activities").addSnapshotListener {  snapshot, error    in
            guard let activityDocuments = snapshot?.documents else {
                print ("Error fetching: \(error)")
                return
            }
            self.activities = activityDocuments.compactMap { activity in
               try? activity.data(as: Activity.self)
            } ?? []
            print(self.activities)
        }
    }
    //Called when a user hits Post Activity
    func postActivity(activity: Activity) {
        print("postActivity")
        do {
            try db.collection("activities").addDocument(from: activity)
        } catch let error {
            print("Error writing activity to Firestore: \(error)")
        }
    }
    //Called when a user hits Join Activity
    func updateActivity(activityUID: String, userUID: String) {
        let ref = db.collection("activities").document(activityUID)
        ref.updateData([
            "members": FieldValue.arrayUnion([userUID])
        ])
}
```